# Одинаковый дизайн Android-приложений на всех устройствах

Tags: android, дизайн

При дизайне разметки своего Android-приложения я всегда использовал dp (как везде советуют).

Но при запуске в Genymotion на различных устройствах (с одинаковым разрешением!) Samsung Google Galaxy Nexus 720x1280 и Sony Xperia S 720x1280 у меня уже много элементов отображаются по-разному, что уж говорить про устройства с бóльшими разрешениями. Некоторые элементы вообще друг под друга уехали.

В чём проблема? Как тогда делать приложения с дизайном, одинаковым на всех устройствах?

Answer (score 2):

Невозможно сделать одинаковый дизайн для всех приложений в dp. `DiP` (density-independent pixel) дословно плотность-независимый пиксель. Эта величина зависит не от разрешения экрана устройства, а от физического размера.

А попробуйте посмотреть какие различия будут между Nexus One и Motorola Nexus, если при таких минимальных различия у Вас уже все рассыпалось.

Из простейшего - используйте `LinearLayout`, элементам раздайте `weight` и посмотрите результат. От этого и отталкивайтесь.

Comment: я нашел много информации, что при `LinearLayout` похоже смотрится, чем при других разметках. А что делать, если у меня всё приложение построено на `RelativeLayout`? похоже проблема именно в этом..

Comment: Еще узнал, что при `margin`-е нужно обязательно использовать оба варианта отступа с краёв: Start+left/Right+end, т.к. на разных устройствах будет отображать по-разному. может кому-то пригодиться)

Comment: С `RelativeLayout` тоже можно жить, если плясать не только от левого края, но и от правого и не задавать ширину контролов точно, а использовать `layout_toLeftOf` и `layout_toRightOf`. Но с `LinearLayout` жить проще и быстрее рендерится.